# Perform a full swipe left action in UI Tests?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have implemented leading and trailing swipe actions in a table view. Now, I'm trying to test them in XCTest UI tests.

To test a regular swipe in either direction is easy:

```
tableCell.swipeRight()
tableCell.swipeLeft()
```

Using one of these causes the 1st action button to be displayed, and I can then `.tap()` on the button.

However, testing a full swipe is proving a little more challenging. I have played with [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46708494/1107226) from [How do I swipe faster or more precisely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280821/xctest-swift-how-do-i-swipe-faster-or-more-precisely)

I have also played with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37159933/1107226) from the question [Xcode7 ui testing: staticTexts[“XX”].swipeRight() swipes not far enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158631/xcode7-ui-testing-statictextsxx-swiperight-swipes-not-far-enough).

Both of these essentially use [XCUIElement's coordinate(withNormalizedOffset:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500960-coordinatewithnormalizedoffset) method to swipe from one point to another, similar to the following:

```
let startPoint = tableCell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector.zero)
let finishPoint = startPoint.withOffset(CGVector(dx:xOffsetValue, dy:yOffsetValue))
startPoint.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: finishPoint)
```

I ended up with an extension that *successfully performs a full swipe right* - but I can't seem to get the numbers right for a *full* swipe **left**.

My code does perform a swipe left, but just doesn't go far enough. I've tried hardcoded numbers for `dx:` from -300 to 300. The element width is 414. I believe that 0 is the far left, and 414 would be the far right, so I started using that size as a reference. Still, no joy.

How can I get this to perform a full swipe left?

```
extension XCUIElement
{
    enum SwipeDirection {
        case left, right
    }

    func longSwipe(_ direction : SwipeDirection) {
        let elementLength = self.frame.size.width
        let centerPoint: CGFloat = elementLength / 2.0
        let halfCenterValue: CGFloat = centerPoint / 2.0

        let startOffset: CGVector
        let endOffset: CGVector
        switch direction {
        case .right:  // this one works perfectly!
            startOffset = CGVector.zero
            endOffset = CGVector(dx: centerPoint + halfCenterValue, dy: 0)
        }
        case .left:  // "There's the rub" as Hamlet might say...
            startOffset = CGVector(dx: centerPoint + halfCenterValue, dy: 0)
            endOffset = CGVector.zero

        let startPoint = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: startOffset)
        let finishPoint = startPoint.withOffset(endOffset)
        startPoint.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: finishPoint)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

- First, I didn't need to use the frame size of the cell. The "normalized" part means that you can use values from *0.0* to *1.0* to represent a percentage of an element's size.
- Second, playing with the sizes, I found a long swipe needs to move about 60% of the width of the cell in order to activate the action.

My resulting long swipe extension:

```
extension XCUIElement
{
    enum SwipeDirection {
        case left, right
    }

    func longSwipe(_ direction : SwipeDirection) {
        let startOffset: CGVector
        let endOffset: CGVector

        switch direction {
        case .right:
            startOffset = CGVector.zero
            endOffset = CGVector(dx: 0.6, dy: 0.0)
        case .left:
            startOffset = CGVector(dx: 0.6, dy: 0.0)
            endOffset = CGVector.zero
        }

        let startPoint = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: startOffset)
        let endPoint = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: endOffset)
        startPoint.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: endPoint)
    }
}
```

Note: `CGVector.zero` is a Swift alias for `CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)`